# WPF MVVM Pattern - Control Binding not working

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF-MVVM pattern. I have written a small application which performs addition of two numbers. The two numbers are entered in by the user while the addition is performed when a button is clicked.

The problem is that the `Result` is not binding to the third text box.

Following is my code (being new to MVVM, if you find addition problems, please let me know):

App Class - Startup

```
public partial class App : Application
{
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            MVVM_Math_Calc.Views.Calculator calc = new Views.Calculator ();
            MVVM_Math_Calc.ViewModels.CalculatorViewModel context = new ViewModels.CalculatorViewModel ();
            calc.DataContext = context;
            calc.Show();
        }
    }
```

View

```
<Window x:Class="MVVM_Math_Calc.Views.CalculatorWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Calculator" Height="200" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
           <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
           <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>    
        <Label Content="Number 1"   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="Blue" />
        <Label Content="Number 1"   Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="Blue" />
        <Label Content="Result"     Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="Blue" />    
        <TextBox Name="Num1"        Text="{Binding Number1}"    Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Gray" />
        <TextBox Name="Num2"        Text="{Binding Number2}"    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Gray" />
        <TextBox Name="Answer"      Text="{Binding Result}"     Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Gray" />    
        <Button Content="Addition"  Command="{Binding Path=AddNumbersCommand}"       Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" /> 
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CalculatorViewModel

```
public class CalculatorViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
        private CalculatorModel calculatorModel;
        private ICommand        additionCommand;

        public CalculatorViewModel ()
        {
            this.CalculatorModel = new CalculatorModel (20, 10);
        }

        public CalculatorModel CalculatorModel
        {
            get
            { return calculatorModel; }
            set
            { calculatorModel = value; }
        }

        public int Result
        {
            get { return this.CalculatorModel.Result; }
            set { this.CalculatorModel.Result = value; }
        }

        public int Number1 
        {
            get { return this.CalculatorModel.Number1;  }
            set { this.CalculatorModel.Number1 = value; }
        }

        public int Number2 
        {
            get { return this.CalculatorModel.Number2;  }
            set { this.CalculatorModel.Number2 = value; }
        }

        public ICommand AddNumbersCommand
        {
            get 
            {
                if (additionCommand == null)
                {
                    additionCommand = new DelegateCommand(param => AddNumbers());
                }

                return additionCommand; 
            }
        }

        public void AddNumbers ()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine ("Addition");
            this.CalculatorModel.Result = this.CalculatorModel.Number1 + this.CalculatorModel.Number2;
            this.Result = this.calculatorModel.Result;
        }
    }
```

CalculatorModel

```
public class CalculatorModel : ViewModelBase
{
        private int num1;
        private int num2;
        private int result;

        public CalculatorModel ()
        {}

        public CalculatorModel (int n1, int n2)
        {
            this.Number1 = n1;
            this.Number2 = n2;
            this.Result = 0;
        }

        public int Number1
        {
            get
            { return num1; }

            set 
            {
                if (value != num1)
                {
                    num1 = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Number1");
                }
            }
        }

        public int Number2
        {
            get
            { return num2; }

            set
            {
                if (value != num2)
                {
                    num2 = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged ("Number2");
                }
            }
        }

        public int Result
        {
            get
            { return result; }

            set
            {
                if (value != result)
                {
                    result = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged ("Result");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

ViewModelBase

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // event handler
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged (string propertyName)
        {
            this.VerifyPropertyName (propertyName);
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public virtual void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
        {
            // Verify that the property name matches a real,
            // public, instance property on this object.
            if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
            {
                string msg = "Invalid property name: " + propertyName;
                throw new Exception ("Error");
            }
        }
    }
```

DelegateCommand

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
        readonly Action<object>     _execute;
        readonly Predicate<object>  _canExecute;

        public DelegateCommand (Action<object> execute) : this (execute, null)
        {}

        /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
        public DelegateCommand (Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public bool CanExecute(object parameters)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameters);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameters)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Execute");
            _execute (parameters);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try binding to CalculatorModel.Number1, CalculatorModel.Number2 and  CalculatorModel.Result instead of having the viewmodel expose those properties as extra properties.  Also Raise the PropertyChanged event for CalculatorModel property in your viewmodel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding to `CalculatorViewModel.Result`, which does not raise a property change notification when the value changes. WPF bindings use the notification to know when they should update.

Two solutions :

1. Bind to `CalculatorModel.Result` instead of to `CalculatorViewModel.Result`

   ```
   <TextBox Name="Answer" Text="{Binding CalculatorModel.Result}" .. />
   ```
2. Or raise the PropertyChanged event for `ViewModel.Result` whenever `Model.Result` changes.

   For example :

   ```
   public CalculatorModel CalculatorModel
   {
       get { return calculatorModel; }
       set
       { 
           // remove old event if necessary
           if (calculatorModel != null)
               calculatorModel.PropertyChanged -= CalculatorModel_PropertyChanged;

           calculatorModel = value; 

           // attach a propertyChanged event to re-raise for ViewModel
           if (calculatorModel != null)
               calculatorModel.PropertyChanged += CalculatorModel_PropertyChanged;
       }
   }

   private void CalculatorModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.PropertyName == "Result")
           OnPropertyChanged("Result");
   }
   ```

Typically I use #1 unless there is a good reason not to.

Comment: Rachel, you are right. Binding to the Model did the trick. I also ended up removing the properties from the ViewModel.

Comment: Rachel, since I am new to MVVM, I am not very clear on how the "DelegateCommand" works especially the CommandManager. Kindly, could you explain this class a bit since this is used as a standard across MVVM.

Comment: Last but not the least, how can I bind to a collection of objects. I saw ObservableCollection<T> being exposed as a property. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: @CodingGeek A delegate command is basically something that allows the View to say "run command X", but it doesn't need to know where commandX is, or have a direct reference to wherever it is implemented. For example, VM can say "SaveCommand points to DataService.Save", and the View doesn't need a reference to the DataService to execute the command.

Comment: @CodingGeek In regards to bindings, I would recommend making sure you understand wpf's `DataContext` first. I actually have a blog article I wrote just so I could link to it from SO: [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/). Hopefully that can give you a good starting point :)